# SRAM AXS double to single

Tags: crankset, chainring, sram

I'm looking at a road bike with SRAM Force AXS 2x crank but would like it as 1x. I see from photos that the spider is separate from the right crank.

Are the 1x vs 2x arms and/or spiders different?

If arms and spiders are the same, I can just replace both rings with a single 1x-specific one. If the arms are the same but the spiders differ, I have to get the 1x spider as well, and if the arms differ I have to replace the whole thing. The seller don't do any customization so I can't ask them to swap.

Comment: Yes the single ring and double ring spiders will be different. The single ring spider positions the single ring on the nominal chain-line, the double ring places the two rings straddling it,

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done it, but I am pretty sure it's doable without purchasing a new crank.

SRAM shows that switching between AXS 2x and 1x is as simple as changing the chainring:

However, if you have AXS *Wide* 2x, it's 94mm BCD (vs. 107mm), so you will need both a new spider and a new chainring (AXS narrow-wide 1x chainring with 107 BCD).

Answer (score 2):

You can run a 1x setup on a 2x crank. You need to adjust the position of the chainring to maintain a proper chainline using a) spacers at the bottom bracket and/or b) offset chainrings.
I have put my 1x chainring in place of the smaller chainring of the 2x crank and spaced to bottom bracket out.

It should also be possible to replace the 2x spider with a 1x

Comment: Note that moving the crank laterally at the bottom bracket to adjust the chain line is usually not possible with a SRAM GXP bottom bracket. At least it would require considerable effort.